# Python CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when hitting jenkins on https (cert is valid though)

Tags: python, ssl, jenkins, jetty

I just followed the instructions on using https in Jenkins: [How To Setup HTTPS within Jetty](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219001547-How-to-setup-HTTPS-within-Jetty-) and everything comes up fine.  When I hit it from any browser, it is secure:

[image: Valid HTTPS]

Unfortunately, when I use python to interact with Jenkins I now get an error:

```
import urllib2
import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://jenkins.clearcareonline.com:8443')

OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "foo.py", line 6, in 
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://jenkins.clearcareonline.com:8443')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError:

I'm on a Mac.  As you can see, I even tried updating my openssl package (originally it was OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016) and I get the same error.

This is why I think it's related to Jenkins (or how Jenkins is launched via Jetty):  I am using the SAME cert for another secure application and I can run the same script and it works just fine.

In other words, using the same cert:

```
This fails:  urllib2.urlopen('https://jenkins.clearcareonline.com:8443')
This passes: urllib2.urlopen('https://apps.clearcareonline.com')
```

So something in the way Java 8 is launching Jetty is causing a CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error in python. I'm using Python 2.7.12.  It's not just on Mac too. I spun up an AWS linux box and I get the same results.

Any ideas on how to start Jenkins so that I don't get that python error?
Maybe throw an ELB/nginx in front of Jenkins and do cert termination on the ELB? I also added "JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" to my /etc/sysconfig/jenkins but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you using a wildcard certificate on your http server that matches *.XXXX.com?

Comment: Your code claims to connect to `jenkins.XXXX.com:8443` while the stacktrace shows `https://admin.clearcareonline.com:443`.  Do you really get problems validating the URL from the stacktrace or the URL shown in your call to `urlopen` or both?

Comment: Doh! I wanted to black out the actual url. I'll go ahead and place the actual URL, since I plan on changing it anyway. I copied and pasted the wrong URL.  Yes. I'm using a wildcard cert.

Comment: To verify both the good and bad url are using the same cert, I used:  https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://jenkins.clearcareonline.com:8443 and https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://apps.clearcareonline.com